# Matrix transformation for vectors in $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Need verification if the solution is correct and if it requires more depth thanks.

Given Matrix transformation matrix

$$A =\begin{pmatrix} 1 &   1 & 1 \\
              0 &   2 & 2 \\
              0 & 0 & 3  \end{pmatrix}$$

Are there vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ that do not change under this transformation, i.e. such that $T(u) = u$ ? Explain why yes or why not.

My Ans: No since for any linear transformation $T$ from $V=\Bbb R^3$ there is an $m\times n$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$ such that transformation  can be represent as $T(u)=\mathbf{A}u$ for all $u \in \Bbb R^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=\begin{pmatrix} \lambda \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ for any $\lambda$

A little work shows that these are the only solutions to $\mathbf{A}u=u$.

A note:  no matter what linear transformation you have, $T(0)=0$ is always true, but sometimes students forget to state the whole problem, so I posted a complete set of solutions just in case. :-)

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 &   1 & 1 \\ 0 &   2 & 2 \\
              0 & 0 & 3  \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}\iff \begin{pmatrix} x+y+z \\
              2y+2z \\
              3z \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} x \\
              y \\
              z \end{pmatrix} \iff \begin{pmatrix} y+z \\
              y+2z \\
              2z \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\
              0 \\
              0 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Third equation gives $z=0$ and first equation gives $y=0.$ So,

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 &   1 & 1 \\ 0 &   2 & 2 \\
              0 & 0 & 3  \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}.$